# Get current user name, that is logged in SharePoint 2010 portal

Tags: sharepoint-2010, authentication, caml

How to get current user name (that is logged in sp portal) in CAML code?
I want to create filter like this:

```
<Where>
 <Eq>
   <FieldRef Name="Reporter"/>
   <Value Type="Text">CurrentUserName</Value>
 </Eq>
</Where>
```

Reporter - is text field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible, it would be better if 'Reporter' is a 'User' field.  This allows for population of this field with the people picker control.  It will also allow this CAML query to work.

```
<Where>
    <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name=’Reporter’ LookupId=’TRUE’/>
        <Value Type=’Integer’><UserID/></Value>
    </Eq> 
</Where>
```